# upper_bound and lower_bound inconsistent value requirements

Tags: c++, stl, implicit-conversion, lower-bound, upperbound

I saw what looks like an inconsistency in the std::lower_bound() and std::upper_bound() syntaxes (well, type-conversion, really) and was wondering if anyone could elucidate please? Per the comments, line 2 will not compile despite its obvious similarity to line 1; you need to use the form shown on line 3 (on gcc 4.7.3 / ubuntu 64-bit at least - that's all I've got to play with)

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class MyInt {
  private:
    int val;
  public:
    MyInt(int _val): val(_val) {}
    bool operator<(const MyInt& other) const {return val < other.val;}
};

int main() {
    set<MyInt> s;
    s.insert(1);  // demonstrate implicit conversion works
    s.insert(MyInt(2));
    s.insert(3); // one last one for the road
    set<MyInt>::iterator itL = lower_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), 2); //LINE 1
    // the line below will NOT compile
    set<MyInt>::iterator itU = upper_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), 2); //LINE 2
    // the line below WILL compile
    set<MyInt>::iterator itU2 = upper_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), MyInt(2)); // LINE 3
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same behavior with g++ 4.8.4 here. It's definitely a g++ bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's a bug. If you look at the [(possible) implementation of `std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound), the comparison is done like

```
if (!(value < *it)) { ... } // upper_bound, implicit conversion `MyInt`->`int` doesn't work
```

And because `operator<` is a member function of `MyInt` (and not of `int`, which is not a class type), the code doesn't compile, since there is no conversion from `MyInt` to `int`. On the other hand, in [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), `*it` appears on the lhs of the comparison, and `value` (of type `int`) can be implicitly converted to `MyInt` when passed to `MyInt::operator<`.

```
if (*it < value) { ... } // lower_bound, implicit conversion `int`->`MyInt` works
```

This is the reason why it's better to implement comparison operators as non-members, so you don't have this asymmetry. This is also mentioned in Scott Meyers' *[Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876)* book: *Item 24: Declare non-member functions when type conversions should apply to all parameters*.

<del>Quick and dirty fix: define an `MyInt::operator int(){return val;}` for implicit conversion `MyInt` to `int`</del>. (**EDIT:** doesn't really work, ambiguity). What works is removing the need for implicit conversion

```
set<MyInt>::iterator itU = upper_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), MyInt(2));
```

instead.

Comment: good digging there, thanks! Interesting that the STL implementation (arguably) confounds its interface. Yet another reason to loathe implicit type conversions

Comment: @aho Yes, a super good reason, great question btw. The `std::upper_bound` can probably be "fixed" if we we perform an additional conversion from `value` to `*it` and store it into a temporary, then use the latter in the comparison. In this case, the behaviour will be exactly similar to `std::lower_bound`, and there is no price to pay (you pay it anyway if you want the code to compile).